# WordPress does not load page.php, return 404.php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming, themes

I am developing a theme for WordPress by following some tutorials. The main page works well, loading post of a custom post type, and the page to see the contents of the cpt also following the Wordpress nomenclature: `single-{name-cpt}.php`.

The problem is when I create a normal page. When entering the URL of the page, the error page appears `404.php`.

I have refreshed the link structure and verified that the `.htaccess` is correct.

What could be happening so that it does not load `page.php`?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Custom links structure: `/blog/%postname%/`

Comment: Maybe this is better suited to the WordPress stack? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're right, I'm going to try there too and I'll keep checking this thread too